# How to divide paragraph by numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a paragraph that contains some numbers into some spaces in it like the following:

```
test test test 98 test 12 test test 877 test
```

I want to divide in into many paragraphs, bullets, or lines depending on separating by numbers, so it becomes the following:

```
test test test 98
test 12
test test 877
test
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Comment: @DavidPostill In fact I know how to find but when coming to replace, I don't want to lose numbers, are you have any idea about how replace with what I found + anything?

Comment: Http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214204 try finding any numerical, then replace with same in then add a special paragraph mark. See if that works

Comment: Here are some other [special characters](http://web.archive.org/save/support.microsoft.com/kb/214204) you can use in Word to find special characters.

Comment: [Wildcards work in Word 2007, too.](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HA012303929990&NS=WINWORD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using:

Find what: ([0-9]* )

Replace with: \1^p

The space after the asterisk is important. Leaving it out breaks up the numbers. ([0-9]* ) finds a digit 0-9 with a space after it.  \1 includes the found text in the replacement, so you don't lose numbers.

There's a good description of the wildcard symbols used here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f#__toc286834992

Comment: great, works perfectly

Comment: You probably don't really need or want the space in the replace string.

Comment: @G-Man I'm not looking for considering where the spaces were, I just want to achieve separation with or without spacing.

Comment: Good point, G-Man. Edited to remove the space.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Word had its own set of regular expressions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f), as @DavidPostill pointed out. A bit fiddling learned me that if you search for `( [0-9]@ )` and replace for `\1^p` gives the desired result. Don't forget to check "Use wildcards".

A short explanation of the characters used:

- `()` is a grouping, which allows to use `\` and a number to refer to that group in "replace with"
- `[0-9]` is a number
- `@` is on or more of the previous character
  ^p` is a new alinea

As @sunk818 noted, according to [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US%5D), this works from MS Word 2010 and further.

Comment: Should be noted that regular expressions work in recent versions of Microsoft Word. This [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US]) suggests it applies to Word 2010 and newer versions of Word?

Comment: @agtoever this answer not so right, as it separates even the digits of the number, so a number like **234** will be separated into **three** lines, but the accepted answer mask works perfectly.

Comment: [Wildcards work in Word 2007, too.](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HA012303929990&NS=WINWORD)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: Are you sure you're doing it correctly? This answer works correctly for me (on Microsoft Word 2007).

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat I had an error in my "search for" statement. Corrected it now. Note that the `*` in the answer of @Kelly-Tessena-Keck also matches for example `123test ` and `123test123 `, while my answer strictly accepts: a space, more than one number and a space.

Comment: @agtoever yea, now it works ad can be considered another working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word 2003, you can use:

Find: `^#^#`

Replace With: `^&^p`

Then another set:

Find: `^#^#^#`

Replace With: `^&^p`

The first search replace will process all the two digits numbers, the second will process all the three digit numbers.

Comment: this answer is in correct, as I have a huge paragraph and don't even know if it has a number with five or six digits, also I'm tagged microsoft-word-2010 in my question , I'm not using 2003

Comment: The spaces at the beginnings and ends of your strings aren't showing up (at least not on my browser). Please fix that, and/or (better yet) add words saying where you have spaces in your strings. But note that the question says "like the following". Just because the _example_ text contains only two- and three-digit numbers is not justification to assume that that will be true for the real data, too.

Answer (score -1):

I solved that by copying the whole paragraph to [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) which enabled me to find them `([0-9]+)`, then replacing them with what I found plus a new line `$&\n` which gives me what I want, then copied them back to word document.

Comment: That's disappointing. I was hoping someone could answer the question within Word.

Comment: I know, I wanted that also, anyway it's still an opening question if anyone answers it within word I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try, but the regex in Word is weaker than I thought. I'm not sure if it's even doable (without going to VBA).

Comment: @user1032613 it's very weak in word dude

Comment: -1 Not a Word solution. You can use a modified version of regular expressions in Word 2010 so you should try to attempt a solution inside Word 2010 in you plan on doing this often.

Comment: @sunk818 I didn't mark it as accepted answer, and if you look at comments on this answer you will figure that I'm said "it's still an opening question if anyone answers it within word I'll accept it" , but I added this answer so that if anyone come here to know how to make that he can find a way